# If we do not require login on DocuSign, will signer still have same signature?

Tags: docusignapi

If we choose the option to NOT require the login if the signer has an account, will the signer still use the same signature as if they were logged in to their account?

TIA
-VG

Comment: I'm not sure which option your talking about when you say "NOT require the login", which setting are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the recipient name and email perfectly match those used by the person for their DocuSign membership, they will be matched and their existing signature adoption will be used when they sign.

Comment: "And" they don't have multiple DocuSign accounts on the same site with the same password and the "Signature" you are refering to is the "default" account for that signer, and this all assumes remote signing, not captive signing (which using client id via API to allow embedded signing)

Comment: See above comment and otherwise NO. In general here is a good reference on the ESign Act and UETA https://www.docusign.com/esign-act-and-ueta